# Find all person with specific conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to find all persons that have at least 2 different colors in the last 3 months
and also one unique color before 3 months.

Definition of a unique color = the person must have at least one different color from the last 3 months.

Let's see some example to make it more clear:

| ID | PersonID | Color | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 'black' | '2021-10-25' |
| 2 | 1 | 'black' | '2021-09-25' |
| 3 | 2 | 'green' | '2021-09-25' |
| 4 | 2 | 'yello' | '2021-08-25' |
| 5 | 2 | 'red' | '2021-07-01' |
| 6 | 1 | 'black' | '2021-07-01' |

Excepted output:

| PersonID |
| --- |
| 2 |

Because PersonID = 2, He has a "unique color" = (a red color, before 3 months and it hasn't appeared in the last 3 months.
And also he had at least 2 colors in the last 3 months (green and yellow)

Thanks.

Comment: I'm just going to give you an example to get you started `SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE   Date Between (@3MonthsAgo, @2MonthsAgo) AND Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Tbl GROUP BY Id, Color WHERE Date Between (@2MonthsAgo, GetDate()) AND Count(Color)  > 1)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Where does PersonID 3 come from, it's not in the sample data

Comment: I edited my post.
Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions combined with conditional aggregation

```sql
SELECT PersonID
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID, Color ORDER BY Date DESC),
      PrevColor = LAG(Color) OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY Date DESC)
    FROM Color c
) c
GROUP BY PersonID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Date < DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE()) AND rn = 1 THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN Date >= DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE()) AND PrevColor <> Color THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3313b647d59ef137686d120b791dc2aa)